# How to initialize UiPickerView inside custom tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I am trying to create `PickerView` inside `tableViewCell`. I made my custom cell conform `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocols. I send data array to cell from the controller (I think this doesn't conform to MVC pattern, may be you also can suggest me how to fix that?). But when tableview calls `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` the cell calls pickerView function. However, pickerView function uses *pickerData* which is not initialized yet. How do I fix that?

Below is my code for the cell:

```
class PickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    var pickerData: Array<String>!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.picker.delegate = self;
        self.picker.dataSource = self;
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count // I get fatal error here due to pickerData is nil
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }


}
```

And here is the code for the cell's initialization:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("picker", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PickerTableViewCell
    cell.title.text = fieldModel.editFieldArray[indexPath.row].title
    cell.pickerData = (fieldModel.editFieldArray[indexPath.row] as! PickerEditField).pickerData
    return cell
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Have you tried making your pickerData variable optional, check for it, and set it inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath, lastly reload the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you have reload the components of `PickerView` so make one small change in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and just reload the components of `PickerView` after setting the `pickerData` Array.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("picker", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PickerTableViewCell
    cell.title.text = fieldModel.editFieldArray[indexPath.row].title
    cell.pickerData = (fieldModel.editFieldArray[indexPath.row] as! PickerEditField).pickerData
    cell.picker.reloadAllComponents();
    return cell
}
```

Also in `awakeFromNib` initialize your pickerData object

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.pickerData = Array<String>()
    self.picker.delegate = self;
    self.picker.dataSource = self;
    super.awakeFromNib()

}
```

Comment: OMG, thank you so much for  "cell.unitPicker.reloadAllComponents()".  I would upvote this answer 100 times if I could.  I have several pickers in expanding table cells that would show empty when first loaded but would be perfect if I scrolled them off screen and back, or collapsed and re-expanded them.  I have been tearing my hair out for many hours on this one.   One line of code and it's fixed!