# What is the best way to design a form layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

What is the best way to design a form layout, I've tried using static UITableView, but I don't know if it's a good practice when I have many cells and if I use prototype cells, it's difficult for me to interact with the elements inside the cells. 
Other form is without using UITableView only a UIScrollView, but I don't know which is the best form. 
In short, which is the most used method for design a form layout?

EDIT: I need to achieve something as shown in the image.

EDIT2: In the case of a CustomCell have a picker view inside, it's better that the same cell delegate from the UIPickerView or it should be the viewcontroller that delegates from the pickerview?

Now my CustomCell delegates from a UIPickerView and the options strings array and protocol methods are inside that class, that's okay?, In that case, what can I do when the array is composed of custom objects instead of strings, for example, I have an array of Persons and I need to show in the pickerview the person name, but I need to return to the viewcontroller the person's age. In that case, I have to create other custom cell that manage that array type (and another different one whenever I need it to handle a different type array)?, or is there any way to unify that to avoid having to create many of different cell classes?.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method herein would still be to use UITableView. You can design your own custom cells which gives you better flexibility incase the form changes in the future.

If the cells have similar kind of elements and you want to reduce your workload for the auto layout stuff you can surely go for the UIStackView inside the custom cell you are designing as suggested by Donovan.

The main reason for the usage of the UITableView is that it gives you great flexibility in terms of grabbing the indexPath for a particular row. Even if the form increases in terms of the numbers of rows it needs to hold on to, you do not need to add a separate UIScrollView to the same.

If the design for certain rows changes, while other still being of the same design,  you can still use custom cell and put in a different cell identifier to the new cells and use the "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" and incorporate the new design.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That’s what i'm doing! so, I have another question about that,  I edited the question, please check it again. And thanks!!!!

Comment: I did not understand it fully but hoping it is similar to something this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494594/how-to-initialize-uipickerview-inside-custom-tableviewcell


Also, in terms of the name array being the picker view but the value being returned is an age array, don't you it would be much more easier to use a dictionary in turn. Using a dictionary will reduce the complexity and you can fetch whatever value you want based on the key value pair.

Comment: You are welcome ! Happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

Table views are generally used when you're displaying data to the user of some sort. For your case how about trying a UIStackView. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160646/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views-2) is a guide to get you started.

Comment: @MartinRegas: Do you need the form to be dynamic (change often, or have different fields for different users etc), or will the form always have the same fields?

Comment: Thanks, the form should be dynamic, I updated the question.